# Setting existing cookies to use with libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

does current version of libcurl support firefox 3.0 and above cookies file (cookies.sqlite) ?
I'm trying to set the file to allow cookies to be used when retrieving the data from web address.

```
int return_val = curl_easy_setopt(hCurl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, \..\cookies.sqlite);
```

return_val is zero but i don't get to see the expected data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to parse the SQLite file.

However, there's addon for firefox that exports cookies in Netscape (*.txt) format.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8154